# Hardware I/O with Python

Tags: python, io, kernel, driver, hardware

I'm trying to build a robot using python, but before I start, I want to understand how to input commands to whatever output device I choose. For example, if I wanted to access the screen driver and change a pixels color how would I do that?

Would I have to just download separate modules for each output device, or is there some universal way to access the hardware drivers I don't understand? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear but it depends on the screen and the driver.

Comment: oh ok so extensions to drivers are just written in python basically, and things are cross platform most of the time because people generally have the same hardware?